# How to retrieve and store SharedPreferences? (methodology)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a Spinner in my app.  Whatever is selected in the spinner is best to be kept across sessions so I am using `SharedPreferences` to keep hold of the user's choice.

I am not sure which is the best way to store and retrieve this value when needed.  I guess I see three options.

1. Update `SharedPreferences` for the spinner in its `onItemSelected` listener.  When I need to retrieve the value in my app to make a choice about how to proceed, get the value out of `SharedPreferences`.
2. Update `SharedPreferences` in `onPause()`.  When needing to retrieve the value selected use `spinnerName.getSelectedItem()`.
3. Combination of both.  Update `SharedPreferences` using the listener, when needing the value use `getSelectedItem()` (yeah, not so sure about this one).

This relates to my spinner but I was wondering the same thing about my other UI elements so any advice would be helpful. Is one method more efficient for example or just makes more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go with one

1. Once you do `spinnerName.setOnItemSelected(this)`, it would immediately call the listener method and if you have the logic to store the value in the Shared-preference inside the callback, then it could cause inconsistencies because if the logic to initialize the spinner is in the `onCreate()` method then most probably your Shared preference value would always reset it to the default selected value in the Spinner
2. if you go with the the second choice then the logic to save the value to the Shared Prefs is sound but doing a `spinnerName.getSelectedItem().` is kind of prone to error as opposed to getting the value directly back from the Shared Prefs(Yeah! Why don't you get it directly from the Shared Prefs.)
3. No comments :-P Seriously

Why do you want to over complicate a simple process, because eventually this should not turn into a maintenance nightmare because as soon as the more variables and methods stream it, it could lead to code smells and complex logic for inherently trivial task.

Keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not trying to overcomplicate, just not sure how to do it. :) So saving the pref during `onPause()` is fine.  I don't think I can rely on retrieving the preference from here if I do it that way though as it will only be saved when you exit the app? So I can't use the value while the app is still running.

Comment: Exactly, but onPause() is called even whenever your Activity loses focus, that means showing a dialog too would trigger onPause, best way to do this is on onItemSelected() and try to write logic to ignore saving to the shared preference when you are doing spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(), you can do something with a boolean value which is set to true on the onCreate() and then set to false after doing this line spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(), which would mean your default value does not get stored everytime the spinner's Listener is initialized.

Comment: Well it seems to have no problem initialising with the value last stored in  `SharedPreferences` (I never actually got as far as setting a 'default' value.. however you do that..).  This will do, thanks for the help!